# Group array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array, which contains data as follows:

```
Array    (
[0] => Array (
        [www.google.com] => www.google.com/a
    )
[1] => Array (
        [www.google.com] => www.google.com/a
    )
[2] => Array (
        [www.test.com] => www.test.com
    )
[5] => Array (
        [www.test.com] => www.test.com/c
    )
)
```

I need to grup all links for particular url like this:

```
Array (
 [www.google.com] => Array (
      [0] => www.google.com/a
      [1] => www.google.com/a
      )
 [www.test.com] => Array (
      [0] => www.test.com
      [1] => www.test.com/c
      )
  )
```

Please any help for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we call the first array `$domains`.

```
$groups = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($domains); $i++)
{
    foreach ($domains[$i] as $domain => $url)
    {
         $groups[$domain][] = $url;
    }
}

print_r($groups);
```

That might work...

Comment: please note, that the numeric indexes in the outer array are not consecutive. I suggest using `foreach` for the outer loop as well.